# Session started but after redirect it does not exist?

Tags: php

I made a question today about sessions, so finaly i resolved my problem with it. But now after i start my session and:

```
header('Location: main.php');
```

it redirects mi to this main.php file but whe i ask in this very file:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['uname'])) {

     echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("not set");</script>';
}
```

i get answer not set.Why ? i have set my session. why after redirect when i ask about the existence of this session it says it doesnt exist ?

Comment: Have you called `session_start()` in main.php before trying to use `$_SESSION`?

Comment: And think the problem was that when i "header" to the main file in the same main file i have to put "session_start();"

Answer (score 2):

in every file where you are using session you need to start session.

```
session_start();
```

it seems that you have missed that in main.php.

Add this line at the top of every php page where you are using session.

Comment: So basicly when i do this:  $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;

Comment: it ads the name to the current session

Comment: if it works then do not forgot to accpet this answer :)